# cross compile for 32 bit on 64 bit ubuntu 16.04 using autotools?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, 32bit-64bit, autotools

Currently I'm trying to build a library from source on Ubuntu 16.04 using gnu autotools, I've tried the following

```
./configure CFLAGS="-m32" CXXFLAGS="-m32" && make
```

but that returns and error saying that the linker doesn't understand the file format(which I assume is a 64/32 bit issue)

```
./configure --build x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host i386-pc-linux-gnu && make
```

but when I go to inspect the binaries with `ar x libMagick++.a` and `objdump -t *.o | less`
it displays the format as elf-x86_64

the library is ImageMagick and Protobufs

edit: corrected the commands

Comment: You need to specify `--target` when cross-compiling, not `--host`.

Comment: @Botje That still produces 64 bit binaries
edit: command `./configure --build x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --target i386-pc-linux-gnu`

Comment: Did you `make clean` inbetween? or build in a clean build directory?

Comment: @Botje yes I did run `make clean` and got the same result

Comment: That is incorrect, @Botje.  `--target` is relevant only when the thing being build is itself a tool that creates architecture-specific artifacts (for example, a compiler).  It indicates the architecture for which that tool creates binaries.  On the other hand, for all cross-compiling cases, `--host` indicates the architecture on which the built program will run, and `--build`  indicates the one on which it is being built.

Comment: I stand corrected. Apologies.

Comment: maybe try and install gcc-multilib, which supports 32 and 64 bit compilation. This worked well for me in the past. just make sure to override the symlink to your gcc with the new installation

Comment: @Gal I do have gcc-multilib installed, is there a specific way I have to call it?

Comment: For me, adding `LDFLAGS=-m32` works. `--host=...` doesn't have to work because autotools do not support cross-compilation by default. Each package needs to enable it separately,

Comment: @WilliamB just make sure that when you write "gcc" in the terminal it really uses the gcc-multilib you installed